# Longest common subsequence: multiprocess version errors but sequential version works

Tags: c++, synchronization, fork, barrier, lcs

I've been attempting to solve the [longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) using multiprocessing and multi-threading, and I have implemented a multiprocess version of the code, using the usual dynamic programming approach: generate a score matrix, each element depends on the one to its left, north-west and directly above.

In my multiprocess approach, I have adopted propagating the wavefront along the anti-diagonals of the score matrix, and to make life easy, I have performed a shear transform on said score matrix, so that each antidiagonal is now horizontal (this is for improved memory access):

[image: Shear transform]

Following is my code (admittedly rather long, which allows for some set-up):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

#define LOGICAL_CORES (int) sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF)                         /* Number of 
              logical cores on system: indirectly determines number of processes run */
#define MAX_WORK_SIZE 256                                                         /* Maximum amount 
              of work for each worker process */
#define NUM_ANTIDIAGS (X + Y + 1)                                                 /* Number of anti- 
              diagonals to process */
#define ANTIDIAG_SIZE std::max(X, Y)                                              /* Length of each 
              anti-diagonal of the score matrix */
#define ANTIDIAG_REAL_SIZE ((ANTIDIAG_SIZE + MAX_WORK_SIZE - 1) & -MAX_WORK_SIZE) /* Length of each 
              anti-diagonal in memory: a multiple of MAX_WORKER_SIZE */
#define NUM_WORKERS (ANTIDIAG_REAL_SIZE / MAX_WORK_SIZE)                          /* Total number of 
              worker processes */

// The sizes of the input strings
u_int32_t X, Y;

u_int32_t *back;   /* The back anti-diagonal, read from */
u_int32_t *middle; /* The middle antidiagonal, read from */
u_int32_t *front;  /* The front antidiagonal, written to */

struct sync_container {
    pthread_barrier_t barrier;         /* A barrier, to ensure all threads are synchronised */
    pthread_barrierattr_t barrierattr; /* Barrier attributes */
    std::vector<pid_t> pids;           /* A list of process IDs of the worker processes */
};

u_int32_t *data;
sync_container *sync_data;

std::string seq_1;
std::string seq_2;

void read_files(std::ifstream f1, std::ifstream f2)
{
    if (f1.fail() || f2.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Error reading files; exiting." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    f1 >> X >> seq_1;
    f1.close();

    f2 >> Y >> seq_2;
    f2.close();
}

void shm_setup()
{
    data = reinterpret_cast<u_int32_t *>(mmap(nullptr, 4 * ANTIDIAG_REAL_SIZE * sizeof(uint32_t),
                                              PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, 0, 0));

    back = reinterpret_cast<u_int32_t *>(data);
    middle = back + ANTIDIAG_REAL_SIZE;
    front = middle + ANTIDIAG_REAL_SIZE;

    memset(back, 0, ANTIDIAG_REAL_SIZE * sizeof(u_int32_t));
    memset(middle, 0, ANTIDIAG_REAL_SIZE * sizeof(u_int32_t));
    memset(front, 0, ANTIDIAG_REAL_SIZE * sizeof(u_int32_t));

    sync_data = static_cast<sync_container *>(mmap(nullptr, sizeof(sync_container),
                                                   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, 0, 0));
}

void cleanup()
{
    munmap(data, 3 * ANTIDIAG_REAL_SIZE * sizeof(u_int32_t));
    munmap(sync_data, sizeof(sync_container));
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: [executable] [file 1] [file 2]" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    read_files(std::ifstream(argv[1], std::ifstream::in),
               std::ifstream(argv[2], std::ifstream::in));

    // Initialise shared memory and arrays
    shm_setup();

    // Initialise barrier
    pthread_barrierattr_init(&sync_data->barrierattr);
    pthread_barrierattr_setpshared(&sync_data->barrierattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_barrier_init(&sync_data->barrier, &sync_data->barrierattr, NUM_WORKERS + 1);

    int pid = 0;
    int worker_id = 0;
    for (; worker_id < NUM_WORKERS; ++worker_id)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid) sync_data->pids[worker_id] = pid;
        else
            break;
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&sync_data->barrier);

    for (int antidiag_idx = 2; antidiag_idx < NUM_ANTIDIAGS; ++antidiag_idx)
    {
        pthread_barrier_wait(&sync_data->barrier);
        if (!pid) // worker processes go here
        {
            for (int element = MAX_WORK_SIZE * worker_id; element < (antidiag_idx * worker_id) + MAX_WORK_SIZE; ++element)
            {
                if (!element || element >= ANTIDIAG_SIZE) continue;

                char vert = seq_1[antidiag_idx - 1 - element];
                char horz = seq_2[element - 1];

                front[element] = horz == vert ? back[element - 1] + 1
                                              : std::max(middle[element - 1], middle[element]);
            }
        }
        if (pid) // parent process moves pointers
        {
            back = middle;
            middle = front;
            front = back;
        }
        pthread_barrier_wait(&sync_data->barrier);
    }

    if (!pid) exit(0);

    std::cout << middle[ANTIDIAG_SIZE] << std::endl;
    cleanup();
}
```

Now, this code does *not* work. This is strange, because with a small input size (specifically, `< 256`), this code only spawns one worker process and one parent process to manage it, and it *still* fails.

However, when the `fork()`, various `pthread_barrier_wait()` calls, and `if (pid)` control flow paths are removed in the `for` loop, the code executes perfectly and returns the correct expected length of the LCS between two strings specified in the input files. In other words, it degenerates into effectively a single-threaded, single-process version of the dynamic programming solution, but with the shear transform thing.

There is clearly an issue with my synchronisation, and I can't figure out where it is. I've tried several permutations of adding more `pthread_barrier_wait()`s, but this hasn't led anywhere.

Where is the synch issue, and how may I fix it?

Comment: I am to implement both a multi-threaded and multi-process version. I was under the impression that specifying `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` for the various `pthread_*_t` types would allow them to be used as inter-process synchronisation constructs; at least, this is what [the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.3.html) says. **PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED**     Mutexes created with this attributes object can be shared between any threads that have access to the memory containing the object, **including threads in different processes.**

Comment: sorry I think i was wrong ;). Interesting question. I'll delete my comments (fwiw, I think it is "that have access to the memory containing the object" that is missing, but not sure)